# How can you share a CRM-like phone book with Google Contacts?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, google-contacts

We'd like to share contacts stored in Google Contacts with the entire company. We have 1,000+ client records and phone numbers that we'd like everyone in the company to have access to.

We've been using a traditional CRM for this, but we're doing sales automation in another system now, so it doesn't seem worth it to maintain this CRM just for contact management. Plus, we have a bunch of systems that integrate with Google Contacts, so we'd just like to share a common list of contact information there.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ask your G Suite administrator to enable the Share Contacts feature. For details see [Enable Contact Sharing](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/2468278?hl=en)